# Text and TouchableOpacity Style Type Annotations

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I am trying to type annotate my React Native project using Flow, but I am having trouble finding the type definitions for the `Text` and `TouchableOpacity` elements so I can reference their `style` prop type definitions. How can I import and/or reference the type definitions for these elements?

Code below:

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

type Props = {
    segmentIndex: number,
    segmentInfo: {
        title: string
    },
    segmentStyle: ???, // WHAT SHOULD I USE HERE?
    titleStyle: ???, // WHAT SHOULD I USE HERE?
    onSelection: (number) => void
}

export const SegmentButton = (props: Props) => {
    const _segmentPressed = () => {
        props.onSelection(props.segmentIndex)
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={props.segmentStyle} onPress={_segmentPressed}>
            <Text style={props.titleStyle}>{props.segmentInfo.title.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + props.segmentInfo.title.substring(1)}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to define `StyleSheet` type.

### 1. *react-native* generic way

reference from *react-native* library,

**SwipeableQuickActionButton.js**

```is
import { View } from 'react-native';

type Prop = {
    style?: ?View.propTypes.style,
}
```

### 2. *react-navigation* generic way

reference from *react-navigation* library,

**TypeDefinition.js**

```is
export type Style =
  | { [key: string]: any }
  | number
  | false
  | null
  | void
  | Array<Style>;
```

If you already installed `react-navigation`, import it from:

```is
import type { Style } from 'react-navigation/src/TypeDefinition';

type Prop = {
    style?: Style,
}
```

Or you can still use it by define in your own file.

### 3. make `Style` type specific for `<Text />` and `<TouchableOpacity />`

It would be the hard way -- although doable, see if that worth the trouble.

take `<Picker />` for reference, it defined [`itemStyle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pickerios.html#itemstyle) for `<Text />` like below, which corresponding to text style for each picker item.

```is
var StyleSheetPropType = require('StyleSheetPropType');
var TextStylePropTypes = require('TextStylePropTypes');
var TextStyle = StyleSheetPropType(TextStylePropTypes);

type Prop = {
    itemStyle: TextStyle
}
```

To use it in your own library, import them from:

```is
import TextStylePropTypes from 'react-native/Libraries/Text/TextStylePropTypes';
import StyleSheetPropType from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetPropType';

let TextStyle = StyleSheetPropType(TextStylePropTypes);

type Prop = {
    style?: ?TextStyle,
}
```

Comment: @BryanSills my mistake, didn't read your question carefully. updated my answer.